# What is the difference between tf-nightly-gpu and tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been working for a while with `tensorflow` and now i'm doing the learning staff on the GPU using `tensorflow-gpu`, where it seems like I'm facing a release bug and someone said that using `tf-nightly-gpu-2.0-preview` will solve the issue.

So, what is the difference between `tf-nightly-gpu` and `tensorflow-gpu`, is it a beta version of it or what?

thanks in advance.

Comment: `tf-nightly-gpu` is updated (built and released) ["every" day](https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly-gpu/#history), while the `tensorflow-gpu` is the stable release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are [nightly builds](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Daily_build&oldid=862875322), produced from a time-based snapshot of the source code that may or may not be in good shape and fit for release.

Time-based may literally mean every night, or simply some other regular interval.